# Handlebars.js - If the image_url doesn't contain "questionmark"

Tags: handlebars.js, fetch

I'm learning Handlebars.js. This is my example:

```js
const url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/anime/1/characters_staff';

fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    // Read the response as json.
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // Do stuff with the JSON
    console.log(data);
    createHtml(data.staff);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
  });


// Handlebars function to generate the HTML
function createHtml(ourData) {
  let rawTemplate = document.querySelector("#ourTemplate").innerHTML;
  let compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
  let ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(ourData);

  let ourContainer = document.querySelector("#container");
  ourContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<ul id="container" class="cf"></ul>

<script id="ourTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
  <li class='list-container'>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="{{ image_url }}">
    </div>
    <div class="name-container">
      {{ name }}
    </div>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Some of the data coming back from the API request doesn't have an image. wherever there's no image, a place holder image is shown, which has the "questionmark" in its name.

I want to achieve that the data should be shown only if the image-name doesn't contain "questionmark" in it.

**Is there any way in Handlebars.js to say: Show the data only If the image_url doesn't contain "questionmark"?**

Something like this?

```html
{{#each this}}
  {{#if image_url !contains "questionmark"}}

      <li class='list-container'>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="{{ image_url }}">
        </div>
        <div class="name-container">
          {{ name }}
        </div>
      </li>

  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is the same example on codepen:

[Handlebars.js example](https://codepen.io/itsthomas/pen/WyBazO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (for non node js use) ---------
You can define a helper to do this with this code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('regex', function (data, regex) {
  return (new RegExp(regex).test(data))
})
```

You would then use it like this:

```
{{#each this}}
    {{#unless (regex image_url 'questionmark')}}
    <li class='list-container'>
      <div class="image-container">
        <a href="{{ url }}" target="_blank">
          <img src="{{ image_url }}">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="name-container">
        {{ name }}
      </div>
      <div class='role-container'>{{{ role }}}</div>
    </li>
    {{/unless}}{{/each}}
```

OLD POST (for node js) -------
There's a useful library called handlebars-helpers (https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#regex) which provides some regex helpers. You could test the presence of `questionmark` in the `image_url` like this:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#unless (test image_url (toRegex "questionmark"))}}

      <li class='list-container'>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="{{ image_url }}">
        </div>
        <div class="name-container">
          {{ name }}
        </div>
      </li>

  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I added 
var helpers = require('./node_modules/handlebars-helpers')();
to my JS file. But now I get this error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: I edited the answer above, try the new solution and let me know!

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. Just out of curiosity, will the old answer work only for a Node project?

Comment: I think so. The library I linked (handlebars-helpers) is written in node and distributed via npm which is a tool to manage node dependencies. For example it uses `require` which is a node specific function.